# Setup git in Qt Creator

Tags: git, qt-creator

Can someone explain what git properties in Qt Creator are about?
I've installed Qt Creator & git. There is "General" tab in Creator's "Options->Version control" & there are few options: path to check scripts, path to configuration files & SSH promt command. Should I create these files by myself?
In "git" tab there is field "Prepend to path". Is it path to git? Such as "/usr/lib/git"?
And finally what is command for "Repository browser"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 64-bit **Windows**.

1. Install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).
2. Place `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` in **Tools** > **Options...** > **Version Control** > **Git** > **Prepend to PATH**:

[image]

3. Setup your local git repository in any suitable (Git Bash for example) console (`cd /c/project`, `git init`, `git add *`, `git commit`, `git remote add origin git@someserver:/some/path/to/project.git`, `git push`).
4. Work with your project in Qt Creator via **Tools** > **Git** > **Local Repository** > **Commit...** > **Commit and Push...**

That's all. Probably you'll want to use passwordless SSH key, because Qt Creator can't easily handle SSH password entering (and storing). Some third-party tools can be used for that. If you want to remove the password from your SSH key, use `ssh-keygen -p`.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear ... on step 3 you "cd" into the directory that contains your *.pro file.  Worked for me.  Thanks

Comment: Sure, `cd /c/project` does just that.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when you are using mysysgit under windows, and you have not added it to the PATH, you can set the "Prepend to path" field in the git configuration to this:

> C:\Users\*your account*\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\

In order for git to work.

Answer (score 1):

The General tab contains common options for all VCS systems. The defaults are usually ok, you don't need to touch anything if it works for you. One setting there that you might want to modify is "Wrap submit message at".

In Git options, Prepend to PATH is used to set the path to git in case you don't have it on the system PATH, or you'd like to use a version that is installed elsewhere. This is mostly used on Windows, it is not mandatory.

The Repository Browser is an optional executable that is available through the menu Tools -> Git -> Tools -> Repository Browser. It is convenience only, not mandatory either (I never used it).